# Make two files resize and save to different folders

Tags: php

i have a form that uploads user data and images to Database and folder on the server. I am resizing the images to be no bigger than 1200px in width. 
So the first part (This Works start) of the code is working just fine.
But the second part where i try to make a second image that is 400px in width and be saved to another folder is not working. 
Why is this, anybody have an idea please?

Thank you.

```
    //This Works start

$save_th = $uploadfolder_th . "/" . $upload_DstName[$i]; //This is the new file you saving
$save = $uploadfolder . "/" . $upload_DstName[$i]; //This is the new file you saving
$file = $uploadfolder . "/" . $upload_DstName[$i]; //This is the original file

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ;

$modwidth = 1200;

$diff = $width / $modwidth;

$modheight = $height / $diff;
$tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ;
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ;
imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ;

imagejpeg($tn, $save, 80) ;

//This Works end

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//This is not Working start

$modwidth_th = 400;

$diff_th = $width / $modwidth_th;

$modheight_th = $height / $diff_th;
$tn_th = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth_th, $modheight_th) ;
$image_th = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ;
imagecopyresampled($tn_th, $image_th, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth_th, $modheight_th, $width, $height) ;

imagejpeg($tn_th, $save_th, 80) ;

//This is not Working end
```

Comment: define "not working". are you getting any errors? if no: have you enabled verbose error messages?

Comment: have you enabled verbose error messages? no i have not. I'm not getting the second image at all.